# Suggenstion on focusout function

Tags: ajax, focusout

What I'm trying to accomplish? :
I have provided a search bar, if you type something it will autosuggest you the results. By clicking on the results user will be taken to the reference page. I wanna provide a functionality that if a user clicks outside the result or input box, the result will get disappeared.

What did it take? : 
Html, css, js, php and ajax

Problem? :
I am able to see the results but I have problem with focusout function in jquery. ( I don't know much about jquery ) If I click on the body of my webpage,   the result element doesn't get disappeared.

Half success! :
Well I tried focusout and focusin function on input box, the result element was able to get disappeared but then if I click on any list-item (results) it stopped taking me to the reference page since I used focusout with input box

```
jquery:
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search_bar_input').focusin(function(){
         $('#results').css('display','block') ;
     });
     } );

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#search_bar_input').focusout(function() {
             $(this).val('') ;
             $('#results').css('display','none') ;
         } );    
     } );

Html :      
<form id="search_bar" name="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search a Song or Artist..." name="search_text" onkeyup="findMatch()" id="search_bar_input"/>
</form>     
<div id="results">
</div>



Ajax or something I don't know to be honest. :

function findMatch() {
     var xmlhttp ;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
      } else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") ;
           }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText ;
            }
        }   
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'include/search.php?search_text='+document.search.search_text.value, true) ;
        xmlhttp.send() ;
    }
```

I have a file search.php here is the code

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_GET['search_text']) ) {
   $search_text = $_GET['search_text'] ;
      }
   if(!empty($search_text)) {
   if(mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '' ) ) {
   if(mysql_select_db('getthetrack.com')) {
     $query = "SELECT `Artists` FROM `artist's name` WHERE `Artists` LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%' ";
     $query_run = mysql_query($query) ;
     if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)){
     while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
         echo '<ul class="search_results">';
        $Artists =  '<li class="search_results_items">'.$query_row['Artists'].'</li>' ;
        echo  '<a href="' . $query_row['Artists'] . '.php" id="search_results_items">'.$Artists.'</a>' ;
        echo '</ul>';
     }
     } else {echo "No results found!";}
 }  
 }
  }
```

Any suggestions on the functionality I wanna deliver?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$( "#search_bar_input" ).blur(function() {

});
```

Comment: Bro same as focusout, It is not working. working half, what I mean is result element is getting disappeared but then if I click on any list item , it has stopped taking me to the page, I wanna go to.

Comment: If I try to atach an event on #results element, focusout or blur is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so:

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#results");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: well thanks for your efforts, but now I've lost the results I was getting.

Comment: You used click event and because of this I've stopped getting results, What I tried is TAB and focused the input box, then I got the results but after clicking on anywhere on the body, I stopped getting results afterwards.